# Is Server Side Pagination supported using LINQ Skip Take on Cosmos database?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

Using Cosmos SDK V3.

> Does Cosmos support LINQ skip and Take for server side pagination, in following example?

**Based on my analysis although I'm able to retrieve data however seems query is not doing server side pagination.**

Why do I say that:

I tried using fiddler and put breakpoint at beginning of while loop, to see that cosmos db is called with skip and take. However there was no server side call, seems all data is fetched while calling Count itself.

```
private static async Task ExportAsync<T>(Database database, string paritionKeyName, string partitionKeyPath)
{
    IOrderedQueryable<T> query = database
                                .GetContainer(SourceContainerName)
                                .GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(allowSynchronousQueryExecution: true);
    var totalCount = query.Count();

    int skip = 0;
    int take = MAX_BATCH_SIZE;
    int taken = 0;

    while (taken < totalCount)
    {
        //breakpoint
        var itemsToInsert = query.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList().AsReadOnly();

        await ProcessBatchAsync(database, paritionKeyName, partitionKeyPath, itemsToInsert);

        taken += take;
        skip++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Can you please edit your question and elaborate more?

Comment: `paritionKeyName` -> `partitionKeyName`

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you would want to use server-side pagination where you fetch a chunk of data (say 100 documents) and process that data and then move to the next chunk (fetch next 100 documents). Am I correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri, yes Sir

Comment: @mjwills Yes Filddler has been intercepting I can connection being made etc. into Fiddler

Comment: @mjwills its outdated. question is for SDK v3. there is breaking change between older versions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-pagination says continuation tokens are still a valid option. Can you try it at least?

Comment: @mjwills What is the value of query.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToString()
 `SELECT VALUE root FROM root OFFSET 150 LIMIT 50`
it changes in each iteration of while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what @404 mentioned in the answer, Cosmos DB does support `skip` and `take` by using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses in the query but using this is not really advisable for the following reasons:

- It results in expensive operations in terms of RU consumption.
- It still does not provide server-side pagination as when you execute a query with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, number of documents that you get based on the value of `LIMIT` and it does not tell you if there are more documents available.

More on OFFSET and LIMIT clauses can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit.

In your scenario, the recommendation would be to make use of continuation tokens (as suggested by @mjwills). Using continuation tokens, you can achieve server-side pagination where you request a certain number of items (specified using `QueryRequestOptions`). When the query executes, you get two things back:

1. Documents matching your query and
2. Continuation token if more documents are available matching your query.

You can process the documents received. If you receive continuation token, you send another query to Cosmos DB service (but include the continuation token this time) and the service will return next set of documents.

Please see the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq;

    namespace SO67263501
    {
        class Program
        {
            static string connectionString = "connection-string";
            static string databaseName = "database-name";
            static string containerName = "container-name";
            static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                string continuationToken = null;
                int pageSize = 100;//Let's fetch 100 items at a time
                CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(connectionString);
                Container container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
                QueryRequestOptions requestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions()
                {
                    MaxItemCount = pageSize
                };
                do
                {
                    FeedIterator<dynamic> queryResult = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<dynamic>(true, continuationToken, requestOptions).ToFeedIterator();
                    FeedResponse<dynamic> feedResponse = await queryResult.ReadNextAsync();
                    List<dynamic> documents = feedResponse.Resource.ToList();
                    continuationToken = feedResponse.ContinuationToken;
                    //Do something with the documents...
                } while (continuationToken != null);
                Console.WriteLine("All done...");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate the application.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's supported and can be tested using `ToString()` on the queryable to view the query that's send to the database.

```cs
var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Dictionary<string, object>>()
    .OrderBy(x => x["_ts"])
    .Skip(50)
    .Take(10)
    .ToString();
//result:
//{"query":"SELECT VALUE root FROM root ORDER BY root[\"_ts\"] ASC OFFSET 50 LIMIT 10"}
```

Using `OFFSET` has increasing RU usage in linear fashion. When you have a lot of pages it becomes extremely expensive to use this type of query with the later pages. If possible you're better off using a continuation token or the `WHERE` clause to filter the results.